# Calculating the gas constant of saturated moist air

Tags: thermodynamics

How to calculate the gas constant of saturated moist air at 16 degree Celsius and 1.013 bar?

I'm not sure where to go with this. I just know that the saturated vapor pressure from steam tables, at 16 degree Celsius is 0.018173 bar. Is this data even useful for calculating the gas constant?

Answer (score 3):

$$R=\frac{N_A \, k_B}{M}$$
with [specific gas constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_constant#Specific_gas_constant) $R$, [Avogadro number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant) $N_A$, [Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant) $k_B$ and [molar mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_mass) $M$.

For a mixture of ideal gases (remembering $pV = N k_B T$):
$$x_i = \frac{N_i}{N} = \frac{p_i}{p}$$
with pressure $p$, volume $V$, number of molecules $N$, temperature $T$ and [mole fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_fraction) $x$. Indices refer to individual species, non-indexed values are for the mixture: $p_{\mathrm{Water}}$ = water partial gas pressure, $p$ = total pressure. Remember that $V_i=V$ and $T_i=T$ for mixtures.

Finally (see [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gasgemisch)),
$$M =\sum_j \, x_j \, M_j$$

You have $p_{\mathrm{Water}}$ and $p$, which allows you to calculate $p_{\mathrm{Air}}$ (the difference), all $x_i$, then $M$ and finally $R$.